# reloading a page gives "Cannot GET /dashboard/a@b.com" - angular ui-routing

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

this is the state :

```
.state('userDashboard', {
  url : '/dashboard/:email',
  templateUrl : '/templates/dashboard.html',
  controller : 'dashboard'
 })
```

this is how I reach to this state:

```
$state.go("userDashboard", {email : data.email})
```

now the when I am on this page, the url lookslike:

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/a@b.com
```

the question: when I reload this url(http://localhost:3000/dashboard/a@b.com), I get this error:

```
Cannot GET /dashboard/a@b.com
```

P.S: When i change url to `localhost:3000/#/dashboard/a@b.com`, the page gets loaded correctly and the url automatically changes to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/a@b.com`

Please help me resolve it.

Edit:-
I am using angular on the front end and nodejs at the back end.

Comment: @Phil I am using angular on the front end and nodejs at the back end. I am not able to resolve it by seeing the php solution.

Comment: There's a link in the accepted answer to [this documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) that contains a section on **Express Rewrites**